# Spring Boot application MySQL SocketTimeoutException

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I have an application that uses Spring Boot which runs as a daemon and performs processing once every 24 hours in which it uses MySQL. I released it yesterday and today it attempted to perform processing for the first time but unfortunately I got the following error (relevant stacktrace segments):

```
08:00:31.264 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
...
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
...
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

I doubt that something was wrong with MySQL at that time, I'm more inclined that maybe the connection was stale although I would think that the connection pool should take care of it.

Has anybody encountered a situation like this and was able to resolve it. Please let me know what other relevant information I should post. Here is my `application.properties` without security information of course:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://<server>:3306/<schema>?characterEncoding=UTF-8&useUnicode=true
spring.datasource.username=<username>
spring.datasource.password=<password>
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Relevant content of `pom.xml`:

```
... 
<properties>
    ...
    <mysql-connector-java.version>5.1.38</mysql-connector-java.version>
    <spring.boot.version>2.1.3.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    ...
</properties>

<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql-connector-java.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
...
```

The application uses `JdbcTemplate` which Spring Boot provides.

Answer (score 0):

1) It is happening due inactivity of created database connection

For avoiding it, just you can add following properties in 
  application.properties.

```
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 60000
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
```

This will end the activity by simply firing SELECT 1 query.